# Animations doesn't follow queue when use different fadeLength in animations

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

For example:

I have 10 animations to play, and all they do is animate a hand.
On the first **3** animations, of length **2.5**, I set fadeLength to 0.6. (*first*)
The next **4** animations has length **1.333**, and I set fadeLength to 0.3. (*second*)
On the last **3** animations, of length **2.5**, I set fadeLength to 0.6 too. (*third*)

When I hit play, it plays every animation with `Animation.CrossFadeQueued(name, fadeLength, QueueMode.CompleteOthers)`.
The first three are played corretly (*first*). Then the last three follows (*third*).
Here is the problem, 4 animations of fadeLength 0.3 was skipped (*second*). Just when those 6 (*first* and *third*) animations end, one animation of the 4 (*second*) that had to play is played, but it doesn't end, it freezes.

How can I use different fadeLengths on animation queue? They really have to be in queue so they can fade between them.

#### Code:

```
GameObject HERO = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("hero");
Animation ANIM = HERO.GetComponent<Animation>();

// first
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("long_move0", 0.6F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("long_move1", 0.6F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("long_move2", 0.6F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);

// second
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("small_move0", 0.3F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("small_move1", 0.3F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("small_move2", 0.3F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("small_move3", 0.3F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);

// third
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("long_move3", 0.6F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("long_move4", 0.6F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
ANIM.CrossFadeQueued("long_move5", 0.6F, QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
```

When playing, this order is followed:

1. long_move0
2. long_move1
3. long_move2
4. long_move3
5. long_move4
6. long_move5
7. *freezes in a piece of a small animation*
8. small_move0
9. small_move1
10. small_move2
11. small_move3

Comment: Do you have a code sample for us? It's hard to visualize what you're describing...